# part of area chart not filled vba

Tags: vba, excel, charts

I'm trying to generate area charts that comes out with green colors for values over a threshold, and red values for values under. I'm able to generate the charts, but my problem is that I don't get continuous graphs (they always come out with gap spaces between the different colored values, even if there is a number in the cell that represents the gap in the graph).
Sample code for the graphs:

```
Sub x_Graph()

'Define Chart
Dim c As Chart
Set c = ActiveWorkbook.Charts.Add
Set c = c.Location(Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="RRL")
With c
.ChartType = xlArea
.HasTitle = True
.ChartTitle.Text = Sheets("Control Data").Range("C4").Value
End With

'Delete pre-defined series
Do Until ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count = 0
ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Delete
Loop

With c
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = Sheets("PD").Range("AN$34:AY$34")
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = Sheets("PD").Range("AN$40:AY$40")
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = Sheets("PD").Range("AN$34:AY$34")
.SeriesCollection(2).Values = Sheets("PD").Range("AN$41:AY$41")

'Name series and format size

c.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "HU (days/month)"
c.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "LU (days/month)"
.Parent.Width = 700
.Parent.Height = 450

End With

c.SeriesCollection(1).Select
With Selection
.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
End With

c.SeriesCollection(2).Select
With Selection
.Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 0, 0)
End With

'Format fonts
c.Legend.Select
    With Selection.Format.TextFrame2.TextRange.Font
        .BaselineOffset = 0
        .Size = 14
        .Name = "Arial"
        End With
c.Axes(xlValue).Select
With Selection.TickLabels.Font
     .Size = 14
     .Name = "Arial"
   End With
c.Axes(xlCategory).Select
With Selection.TickLabels.Font
     .Size = 14
     .Name = "Arial"
   End With

End Sub
```

The graphs come out like this:

[image]

With a gap in between the red and green area, even if there's data in the cell.

The input data is in the following format:
[image]
The green is created from the "Good" series and the red is created from "Bad"

And background code:
[image]
etc

Anyone know what could be done?

Many thanks in advance
FN

Comment: Without seeing the data, I don't think we can rule out that it's a data issue. Can you make a [MCVE]?

Comment: Mat's Mug thanks for replying.
I have created a mini version, how do I attach it?

Comment: Mat's Mug:
https://ufile.io/85f2b
Please let me know if it doesn't work.
Many thanks FN

Comment: I'd include all the relevant information *in the question itself*, not behind a download link (which I'm not clicking btw).

Comment: Mat's Mug - I provided screenshots in the original post instead - is this sufficient for you to be able to help? Many thanks for your feedback